# How can I conditionally resave entries based on the value of an entry's field in a Craft 3 Module/Plugin?

Tags: entries, craft3, plugins, modules

Scenario: I want to programatically bulk resave entries in a certain Site in a certain Section of a certain Type.

I have a Craft 3 Module with a Console Controller containing following code:

```
public function actionResaveEntries()
{
    $site = Craft::$app->sites->getSiteById(self::SITE_ID);
    $section = Craft::$app->sections->getSectionById(self::SECTION_ID);
    $entryType = Craft::$app->sections->getEntryTypeById(self::ENTRY_TYPE_ID);

    Craft::$app->getQueue()->push(new ResaveElements([
        'description' => Craft::t('app', 'Resaving {section}, {type} entries', [
            'section' => $section, 'type' => $entryType->name,
        ]),
        'elementType' => Entry::class,
        'criteria' => [
            'siteId' => $site->id,
            'sectionId' => $section->id,
            'typeId' => $entryType->id,
            'status' => null,
            'enabledForSite' => true
        ]
    ]));

    $result = 'something';
    echo "Resaving entries\n";
    return $result;
}
```

This works as expected when running `./craft resave-entries-module/resave-entries/resave-entries` from the command line & also via a cron job.

However, I now want to modify my code to run `Craft::$app->getQueue()->push(new ResaveElements()` only under certain conditions. Specifically, when a deadline (custom date/time field in entry type) has passed.

I tried following, but it doesn't run at all regardless if before or after deadline date. The conditional seems to be ignored.

```
public function actionResaveEntries()
{
    $site = Craft::$app->sites->getSiteById(self::SITE_ID);
    $section = Craft::$app->sections->getSectionById(self::SECTION_ID);
    $entryType = Craft::$app->sections->getEntryTypeById(self::ENTRY_TYPE_ID);

    $entries = Entry::find()
        ->siteId(self::SITE_ID)
        ->sectionId(self::SECTION_ID)
        ->typeId(self::COMP_ENTRY_TYPE_ID)
        ->all();

    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        // Set deadline
        $deadline = $entry->competitionJudgingEnd;
        // Check if after deadline
        $now = new DateTime();
        if ($now > $deadline) {
            Craft::$app->getQueue()->push(new ResaveElements([
                'description' => Craft::t('app', 'Resaving {section}, {type} entries', [
                    'section' => $section, 'type' => $entryType->name,
                ]),
                'elementType' => Entry::class,
                'criteria' => [
                    'siteId' => $site->id,
                    'sectionId' => $section->id,
                    'typeId' => $entryType->id,
                    'status' => null,
                    'enabledForSite' => true
                ]
            ]));

            //$result = 'something';
            echo "Resaving entries\n";
            //return $result;
        } else {
            //$result = 'nothing';
            echo "Not resaving entries\n";
            //return $result;
        }
    }
```

In an effort to troubleshoot, I changed the conditional to `if ($entry->title == "A known title")`, but it also seems to be ignored. I.e. resave not occurring.

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to get this working?

**UPDATE 01:** The conditionals are actually working. There are 3 entries that meet criteria in `$entries = Entry::find()`. However, the loop seems to be stop at the first entry. This entry changes if I change the criteria.

**UPDATE 02:** It looks like the `return $result;` was breaking the loop. Updated code above by commenting out return statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working solution:

```
public function actionResaveEntries()
{
    $site = Craft::$app->sites->getSiteById(self::SITE_ID);
    $section = Craft::$app->sections->getSectionById(self::SECTION_ID);
    $entryType = Craft::$app->sections->getEntryTypeById(self::ENTRY_TYPE_ID);

    $entries = Entry::find()
        ->siteId(self::SITE_ID)
        ->sectionId(self::SECTION_ID)
        ->typeId(self::COMP_ENTRY_TYPE_ID)
        ->all();

    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        // Set deadline
        $deadline = $entry->competitionJudgingEnd;
        // Check if after deadline
        $now = new DateTime();
        if ($now > $deadline) {
            Craft::$app->getQueue()->push(new ResaveElements([
                'description' => Craft::t('app', 'Resaving {section}, {type} entries', [
                    'section' => $section, 'type' => $entryType->name,
                ]),
                'elementType' => Entry::class,
                'criteria' => [
                    'siteId' => $site->id,
                    'sectionId' => $section->id,
                    'typeId' => $entryType->id,
                    'status' => null,
                    'enabledForSite' => true
                ]
            ]));
            echo "Resaving entries\n"
        } else 
            echo "Not resaving entries\n";
        }
    }
}
```